# MongoDB queries to find or update in array doesn't work properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a new project, first time with huge collection of messages with the schema below -

```
 mongoose.model('Messages', {
    owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    messages: [{
        with: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        from: {id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }, user: String},
        to: [{id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }, user: String}],
        sent: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
        message: String,
        seen: {type: Boolean, default: false},
        stared: {type: Boolean, default: false}
    }]
})
```

most of the used queries i use are to find messages of user (owner) with other user (messages.with) where sent date (messages.sent) is greater than date -

```
Messages.findOne({owner: owner.id, "messages.with": user.id, messages.sent: {$gt: mydate}},{messages: 1, owner: 1}, function (err, doc){}..)
```

I should get the document only if there's message greater (after) the date i entered else get nothing.
The date i use in the query is set to new Date('2015-12-04T03:39:23.126Z') for example so i don't see any problem with date format 
and so with update -

```
Messages.update({owner: owner.id, "messages.with": user.id}, {$set:{"messages.$.seen": true}}, function(err, numEffected) {})
```

just doesn't work.
for now i check the data with another function, but just unnecessary.
Please help me figure it out
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

update don't work, i faced the issue, when i use findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, callback). then it worked for me

Comment: I've tried this as well, still same problem. Thanks anyway